# Formatting C:/ in Windows while ubuntu is installed in D:/

Tags: 11.10, wubi, format, windows-vista

I had installed Ubuntu 11.10 through wubi installer in Windows Vista in D:\ a few months ago. I am able to dual boot to anyone OS. But, now I have a problem with the Windows so I want to format my C:\ drive.

Will the current installation of Ubuntu will change on my PC. That is would the Ubuntu will automatically removed from my PC or it would be there for dual boot even after the format ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-install **WUBI** to use Ubuntu after the re-installation of Windows.Do the following

1. Re-install Windows
2. move your *root.disk* file in the **D:\ubuntu\disks** folder to any place you like (except in the *Ubuntu* folder, because reinstalling wubi will delete the ubuntu folder)
3. Install Ubuntu using **Wubi** to **D:**\ partition
4. After installation is finished, replace the *Root.disk* file with the old *Root.disk* file (that we backed up in the *step 2*)
5. Restart.